# Find "my documents" path with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, activexobject

I would like to determine the path of "my documents" folder with Javascript. I need it to specify the folder where I could store the logs of my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SpecialFolders-method of the shell:

```
shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
pathToMyDocuments = shell.SpecialFolders('MyDocuments');
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't access client file system with Javascript for obvious security reasons.

Comment: I'm using IE and ActiveX for my application, you can allow a trusted activeX to access your file system...Or so, I believe

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Ok, so how could I set a folder for the logs of my application on client side without accessing such informations ?

Comment: You want to do logging on the client side ??

Comment: Yep...It's specific ask from the client (the one who bought the app). I know it sounds strange but...

Comment: That is not a correct design, and it would require file system access to the client which is unsafe. You will have to explain that to him.

Comment: Why is it bad or incorrect for an application to access the file-system? The topic is about an application, not a webpage. So if the user trusts the application, why not doing this(everybody trusts every day hundreds of applications)